# Newbie that needs help in changing Scale Axis in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have a graph that is plotted on the following Axis
X-axis going from -200 to 1300 [-200,1300]
Y-Axis going from -800 to 800. [-800,800]

The values that I want to scatter range from
X-Axis [0,735]
y-Axis [0,437]

May I kindly ask you if there's any library/function that does that?
I want to scale/adjust the scale of the points i'd like to scatter ([0,737], [0,437])

I am trying to scatter some points on the draw_court() function that is mentioned [here](https://g-giasemidis.medium.com/create-euroleague-shot-charts-in-python-7ba4aa574644): https://g-giasemidis.medium.com/create-euroleague-shot-charts-in-python-7ba4aa574644.

```
def draw_court(ax=None, color='black', lw=1, outer_lines=True):
    """
    FIBA basketball court dimensions:
    https://www.msfsports.com.au/basketball-court-dimensions/
    It seems like the Euroleauge API returns the shooting positions
    in resolution of 1cm x 1cm.
    """
    # If an axes object isn't provided to plot onto, just get current one
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()

    # Create the various parts of an NBA basketball court

    # Create the basketball hoop
    # Diameter of a hoop is 45.72cm so it has a radius 45.72/2 cms
    hoop = Circle((0, 0), radius=45.72 / 2, linewidth=lw, color=color,
                  fill=False)

    # Create backboard
    backboard = Rectangle((-90, -157.5 + 120), 180, -1, linewidth=lw,
                          color=color)

    # The paint
    # Create the outer box of the paint
    outer_box = Rectangle((-490 / 2, -157.5), 490, 580, linewidth=lw,
                          color=color, fill=False)
    # Create the inner box of the paint, widt=12ft, height=19ft
    inner_box = Rectangle((-360 / 2, -157.5), 360, 580, linewidth=lw,
                          color=color, fill=False)

    # Create free throw top arc
    top_free_throw = Arc((0, 580 - 157.5), 360, 360, theta1=0, theta2=180,
                         linewidth=lw, color=color, fill=False)
    # Create free throw bottom arc
    bottom_free_throw = Arc((0, 580 - 157.5), 360, 360, theta1=180, theta2=0,
                            linewidth=lw, color=color, linestyle='dashed')
    # Restricted Zone, it is an arc with 4ft radius from center of the hoop
    restricted = Arc((0, 0), 2 * 125, 2 * 125, theta1=0, theta2=180,
                     linewidth=lw, color=color)

    # Three point line
    # Create the side 3pt lines
    corner_three_a = Rectangle((-750 + 90, -157.5), 0, 305, linewidth=lw,
                               color=color)
    corner_three_b = Rectangle((750 - 90, -157.5), 0, 305, linewidth=lw,
                               color=color)
    # 3pt arc - center of arc will be the hoop, arc is 23'9" away from hoop
    # I just played around with the theta values until they lined up with the
    # threes
    three_arc = Arc((0, 0), 2 * 675, 2 * 675, theta1=12, theta2=167.5,
                    linewidth=lw, color=color)

    # Center Court
    center_outer_arc = Arc((0, 1400-157.5), 2 * 180, 2 * 180, theta1=180,
                           theta2=0, linewidth=lw, color=color)

    # List of the court elements to be plotted onto the axes
    court_elements = [hoop, backboard, outer_box, inner_box,
                      restricted, top_free_throw, bottom_free_throw,
                      corner_three_a, corner_three_b, three_arc,
                      center_outer_arc]
    if outer_lines:
        # Draw the half court line, baseline and side out bound lines
        outer_lines = Rectangle((-750, -157.5), 1500, 1400, linewidth=lw,
                                color=color, fill=False)
        court_elements.append(outer_lines)

    # Add the court elements onto the axes
    for element in court_elements:
        ax.add_patch(element)
```

I have also switched the court to the other side (switched X and Y Axis)

so basically i would like to plot the below points(Picture 1), in the below graph (picture 2) [Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLBmi.png)
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLRr4.png)
Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some example code, showing how you generate the plot?

Comment: Hello @userE thank you for your answer. 
I am actually using the draw_court() function from this website: https://g-giasemidis.medium.com/create-euroleague-shot-charts-in-python-7ba4aa574644

and then rotating the (X,Y) access. 

And then the coordinates of the shots that I am getting are on the following scale 

[0,737]
[0.437]

I hope this helps

Comment: alright, it would still be good if you included a minimal example here, so that it is easier to reproduce your situation and suggest a solution.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. Do you mean my actual code? 
I only have the draw_court function and the dataframes that i would like to scatter. 
I have updated the original post

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Using the original functions described in the post, except `plot_scatter`, the code below adjust the range of the court that is visible and limits the range of dots drawn in the scatter plot. Note, I simplified the `plot_scatter` function a bit, to remove unnecessary detail. If you want to have the full court visible, don't pass the `xlim` and `ylim` parameters.

```
def plot_scatter(data, marker='o', label='made',
                 xlim=None, ylim=None, title=None):
    """
    Scatter plot of made and missed shots
    """
    if xlim is None:
        xlim = [-800, 800]
    if ylim is None:
        ylim = [-200, 1300]
    plt.figure()
    draw_court()
    plt.plot(data[0], data[1], marker, label=label)
    plt.xlim(xlim)
    plt.ylim(ylim)
    plt.show()
    return
xlim = [0, 735]
ylim = [0, 437]
data = [random.randint(xlim[0], xlim[1], 10), 
        random.randint(ylim[0], ylim[1], 10)]

# scatter shot chart of PAOs
plot_scatter(data, 'x', 'made', xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)
```

Comment: thank you @userE, i tried it and didn't work. 

To make think clearer. I post it an update with the picture.

I would like to plot the  points - picture 1 (with the same scale) on the second graph.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want to do @jah, Do you ask about how to adjust the scaling, or how to select the range where from to select points to plot?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I've mis-understood your question..
Could you not use the [random module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) ?

```py
import random

# set these to whatever your limits are, they can be adjusted with change of scale
XMIN = 0
XMAX = 735

# scale being whatever scale. Perhaps you'll have to make a call
# to int() if scale is a fraction 

xco_ord = random.randint((XMIN * scale), (XMAX * scale))

# and do the same for y
```

Comment: I'm very sure I've mis-understood the question now, 'scatter' from the data from chart in the link rather than 'scatter' in a more random sense.